# iTextSharp 5 : How can you align the page number "x/x" on the right of the footer

Tags: c#, pdf, pagination, itext, footer

I'm new on iTextSharp 5 and I want to know how can I align the page number on this format **CurrentPage/TotalPages** on the right of the footer. When I create a footer with the page numbers and some information about , I manage to write the **CurrentPage/** on the right but the **TotalPages** keeps on the left. This is my code.

```
public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
    {


        double capitalsocial;
        CultureInfo culture;
        string specifier = "N";
        iTextSharp.text.Font pfontfooter = FontFactory.GetFont(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.UNDEFINED.ToString(), 9f, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK);
        iTextSharp.text.Font pfontNumbrePage = FontFactory.GetFont(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.UNDEFINED.ToString(), 13f, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);

        base.OnEndPage(writer, document);
        var tableContainerFooter = new PdfPTable(new[] { 9F, 1f })
        {
            TotalWidth = 550f,
            PaddingTop = -51f,
            SpacingAfter = -50f,
            SpacingBefore = -50f,
            DefaultCell = { BorderWidth = 0}
        };

        var tableFooter = new PdfPTable(new[] { 9F })
        {
            DefaultCell = { BorderWidth = 0, HorizontalAlignment = 1},  //0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right
            TotalWidth = 500f,
            PaddingTop = -51f,
        };
        tableFooter.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        tableFooter.DefaultCell.BorderWidth = 0;
        tableFooter.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = 1;

        cb = writer.DirectContentUnder;
        PdfTemplate templateM = cb.CreateTemplate(50, 50);
        templates.Add(templateM);

        int pageN = writer.CurrentPageNumber;
        String pageText = pageN.ToString() + "/";
        BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);

        float len = bf.GetWidthPoint(pageText, 12);
        cb.BeginText();
        cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 10);
        cb.SetTextMatrix(document.RightMargin + len + 530f, document.PageSize.GetBottom(document.BottomMargin));
        cb.ShowText(pageText);
        cb.EndText();
        cb.AddTemplate(templateM, document.RightMargin + len, document.PageSize.GetBottom(document.BottomMargin));

        tableFooter.AddCell(new Paragraph(new Chunk(new iTextSharp.text.pdf.draw.LineSeparator(-0.2F, 131F, BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, 9))));

        tableFooter.AddCell(new Paragraph(raison_sociale + " " + forme_juridique + " au capital de " + capital + "" + devise, pfontfooter));
        tableFooter.AddCell(new Paragraph("I.F: " + idfscal + " - R.C.: " + rc + " - Patente: " + patente + " - C.N.S.S: " + cnss + " - I.C.E: " + ice, pfontfooter));
        tableFooter.AddCell(new Paragraph("Tél.: " + tel1 + " - Fax: " + fax + " - Mail: " + email, pfontfooter));

        tableContainerFooter.AddCell(new PdfPCell(tableFooter) { BorderWidth = 0f, });

        tableContainerFooter.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 45f, document.Bottom + 55f, writer.DirectContent);

    }

    //write on close of document
    public override void OnCloseDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
    {
        base.OnCloseDocument(writer, document);
        BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
        foreach (PdfTemplate item in templates)
        {
            item.BeginText();
            item.SetFontAndSize(bf, 10);

            item.SetTextMatrix(document.RightMargin, document.PageSize.GetBottom(document.BottomMargin));

            numberOfPages = writer.PageNumber;
            document.Add(new Paragraph("" + (writer.PageNumber)) { Alignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, });
            item.EndText();
        }

    }
```

And this how it looks

[This the footer that I made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtzME.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is no way to get the page number in advance, this can be achieved by generating pdf as a two-step process.

1. Generate the PDF without page numbers.
2. Render the pdf again, now adding a number on each page.

Once you have generated your pdf, call this method :

```
AddPageNo("Sushant_Without_pageNo.pdf","Sushant_With_pageNo.pdf");
```

You need to define this method as :

```
void AddPageNo(string fileIn, string fileOut)
{
    byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileIn);
    Font blackFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(bytes);
        using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, stream))
        {
            int pages = reader.NumberOfPages;
            for (int i = 1; i <= pages; i++)
            {
                ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(stamper.GetUnderContent(i), Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, new Phrase(i.ToString(), blackFont), 568f, 15f, 0);
            }
        }
        bytes = stream.ToArray();
    }
    File.WriteAllBytes(fileOut, bytes);
}
```